# firefox addon sdk localStorage

Tags: javascript, firefox

localStorage work well in Chrome extensions,but can not save in Firefox addons.
I have data/options.htm,data/options.js to save localStorage,and I change it to require("sdk/simple-storage"),appare ReferenceError: require is not defined.
if the require() should be in lib folder?
if so,how I put the options.htm and options.js and make them work?

Comment: This is how localStorage works in Firefox; [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). There is no mention of needing any additional resources, so what sdk are you referring too?

Comment: localStorage in Firefox addons will not save when Firefox restart , you can try.

Comment: The question is not clear, is localStorage the same localStorage I am referring to or not? I have to assume it is. What are you trying to accomplish? Session persistence? Cookies provide this.